# Converting Input type text to textarea

Tags: html

I am working on backend of my android application for which I have this code

```
<input type="text" name="optiona" class="form-control text-hint" required id="inputName" value="">
```

But it only allows me to input a single line value but I want to write multiple lines.

Can anyone tell me how can I modify the above code to accept multiple line of values and display it as such in the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple lines require the textarea tag. So your textarea of, say 5 lines, might look like this:

```
<textarea name="optiona" class="form-control text-hint" rows="5" required id="inputName"></textarea>
```